# Regular expression, trimming after a particular sign and neglecting the list terms which do not have that sign

Tags: python, regex

```
file = open('SMSm.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('SMSw.txt', 'w')
debited=[]
for line in file.readlines(): 
    if 'debited with' in line:  
        import re
        a= re.findall(r'[INR]\S*', line)
        debited.append(a)
        file2.write(line)

print re.findall(r'^(.*?)(=)?$', (debited)
```

My output is [['INR 2,000=2E00'], ['INR 12,000=2E400', 'NFS*Cash'], ['INR 2,000=2E0d0']]

I only want the digits after INR. For example ['INR 2,000','INR 12000','INR 2000']. What changes shall I make in the regular expression?

I have tried using str(debited) but it didn't work out.

Comment: Sounds like you want to match the *literal* `INR` rather than [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[INR]`. Could try something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/sP5qS0/1): `\bINR\s+\d+(?:,\d+)*`

Comment: @Jonny5 I have the lines but I wanted to trim the output. For that I used print re.findall(r'^(.*?)(=)?$', (debited). But I am getting an error on using the expression

Comment: @Jonny5 when I use the regex you suggested, my compiler gives a list of empty [ ].

Comment: How about: `\S+(?==)` [to get *non-whitespaces* before](https://regex101.com/r/sP5qS0/2) `=` try: `p = re.compile(ur'\S+(?==)')` `re.findall(p, test_str)`

Comment: It worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex matching `INR` + whitespace if any + any digits with `,` as separator:

```
import re
s = "[['INR 2,000=2E00']['INR 12,000=2E400', 'NFS*Cash']['INR 2,000=2E0d0']]"
t = re.findall(r"INR\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)*)", s)
print(t) 
# Result: ['2,000', '12,000', '2,000']
```

With `findall`, all captured texts will be output as a list.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/0ldULe)

If you want `INR` as part of the output, just remove the capturing round brackets from the pattern: [`r"INR\s*\d+(?:,\d+)*"`](https://ideone.com/QxljWi).

**UPDATE**

Just tried out a [non-regex approach](https://ideone.com/G6SKWr) (a bit error prone if there are entries with no `=`), here it is:

```
t = [x[0:x.find("=")].strip("'") for x in s.strip("[]").replace("][", "?").split("?")]
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you already have, the simplest solution is to make the extracted string start with `INR` (it already does) and end just before the equals sign. Just replace this line

```
a= re.findall(r'[INR]\S*', line)
```

with this:

```
a= re.findall(r'[INR][^\s=]*', line)
```